# Problem with ASMX and SPContext.Current equals to null

Tags: web-services, spcontext

I'm deploying my application to an Sharepoint Foundation Farm... In my application there is a web service (tt2sp.asmx) installed in the _vti_bin directory.

On my site the anonymous access is disabled.

When i try to get SPContext.Current it always return me NULL..

Where is the problem? I tried to deploy also in _layouts but the problem was the same..

I checked the web.config looking for anonimous access allows, but seems allright..

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you put the web service straight in the ISAPI folder in the 12/14 hive?

Comment: Yes, already done..

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283513/spcontext-current-is-null-in-a-web-service-under-a-sharepoint-site)?